# Unable to convert varchar to int in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table where I am having data like below.

My requirement is I need to calculate count of machineid when type=R and also when type=C.

So I created a query as shown later on, but I'm getting an error

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'gvpm236b' to data type int.

I tried many ways like convert and cast but not working

This is my query :

```
SELECT
    COUNT (CASE WHEN Type = 'R' THEN CONVERT(int, MachineID) ELSE 0 END) AS 'Non-Persistant',
    COUNT (CASE WHEN Type = 'C' THEN CONVERT(int, MachineID) ELSE 0 END) AS 'Persistant' 
FROM
    table
```

Sample data :

| MachineID | Type |
| --- | --- |
| gvpm236b | R |
| 123456 | C |
| 111 | C |
| 123 | R |

Expected output:

| Non Persistant | Persistant |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | 2 |

Could any one please help how to fix this issue?

Comment: SUM(case when Type='R' then   1 else 0 end) as 'Non-Persistant' , is a bit more clear and you don't need to do any casts

Comment: Hi @siggemannen,
Yeah I tried this.But I have some duplicate machine ids .
when I use sum I am getting them also

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).
All within the question as text, no images.

Comment: then you can do: select count(distinct case when Type='R' then machineid END)

Comment: Your original query won't help against duplicates NOR does it help against anything else, because COUNT(0) is still 1 :) you need to convert value to NULL for it not to count

Comment: HI @siggemannen
When I Use machineid directly I am getting conversion error as I post in my question

Comment: not if you use the real query i post, and not your own version of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works fine for me:

```sql
select count(distinct case when Type='R' then machineid END) AS r
,   count(distinct case when Type='C' then machineid END) AS c
from (
    VALUES  (N'MachineID', N'Type')
    ,   (N'gvpm236b', N'R')
    ,   (N'gvpm236b', N'R')
    ,   (N'123456', N'C')
    ,   (N'111', N'C')
    ,   (N'111', N'C')
    ,   (N'123', N'R')
) t (machineid,type)
```

I added some dups just to test

Answer (score 0):

Since you are counting totals, there is no need to convert `MachineID` to int:

```
SELECT
 COUNT (case when Type='R' then MachineID  end) as 'Non-Persistant',
 COUNT (case when Type='C' then MachineID  end) as 'Persistant' 
FROM table
```

Or using the function `sum()` :

```
SELECT
 SUM (case when Type='R' then 1 else 0  end) as 'Non-Persistant',
 SUM (case when Type='C' then 1 else 0 end) as 'Persistant' 
FROM table
```

To count distinct machines only then :

```
SELECT
  COUNT (Distinct case when Type='R' then MachineID  end) as 'Non-Persistant',
  COUNT (Distinct case when Type='C' then MachineID  end) as 'Persistant' 
FROM table
```

Comment: Hi @SelVazi,

I used this as my first step and getting the same error as I posted in my question

Comment: Updated my answer, can you test using `sum()` ?

Comment: Hi @SelVazi,
The sum answer is working but I need to take only distinct machines ..

Comment: You can use DISTINCT on CASE clause

Answer (score 0):

```
select 
 sum ( case when Type='R' then   1 else 0 end ) as 'Non-Persistant' ,

   sum ( case when Type='C'  then   1 else 0 end ) as 'Persistant' 

 from ddddd
```

distinct Count

```
select count(distinct Non_Persistant),count(distinct Persistant)
from (
        SELECT
          (case when Type='R' then MachineID  end) as 'Non_Persistant',
          (case when Type='C' then MachineID  end) as 'Persistant' 
        FROM ddddd
)s
```

Example Data:

```
create table ddddd(MachineID varchar(100),  Type varchar(100)
)
insert into ddddd
values ('123456'    ,'C')
,('111' ,'C')
,('123' ,'R')
,('gvpm236b'    ,'R')
```